# How make "fire and forget" request sending in spring webflux webclient?

Tags: java, spring, spring-webflux

Consider a code:

```
private WebClient webClient;

public void some(MyObject myObject) {
    return webClient.post()
            .uri("/log/my-path")
            .body(BodyInserters.fromObject(myObject))
            .retrieve()
            .bodyToMono(Void.class)
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.single());
}
```

This code "waits" when response "appears" and then completes. (E.g. `retrieve()` is called). but how not to wait for response? For example, I make request and return `Mono.empty` without waiting for response. How to do that?

**P.S.** A technique when request is sent without wating for response is called "fire and forget".

**UPDATED**

1. Any mono functions like `then` does not work. Because they invocated **after** `bodyToMono` which "waits" until http response is comming. E.g. nothing (event async) is called until `bodyToMono` completes.
2. "remove" `return` statment also does not work. May be in some `main` functions it works but not in Spring application. This does not wok because `Mono` just created in that case, but nobody run it. Any `Mono` methods like `map, flatMap` etc. is just funciton "setting" but not Mono running.

Comment: remove the 'return' statement and and it will be fire in the background. But if you wanted to return Mono.empty then use .then() which is Mono<Void>

Comment: `remove the 'return' statement and and it will be fire in the background.` No, mono will not be run at all in that case.

Comment: Bro, have you solved it?

Comment: just remove return and add .subscribe(). the flow will start on Schedulers.single() thread.

Answer (score 8):

There are several ways to do that.
You could do the following:

```
public void some(MyObject myObject) {
    return webClient.post()
            .uri("/log/my-path")
            .body(BodyInserters.fromObject(myObject))
            .retrieve()
            .bodyToMono(Void.class)
            .subscribe();
}
```

This has an important problem: even if you're not interested in the response itself, you might want to have specific properties like:

- Being notified in case of errors and handling those
- Making sure that, in case of a batch/CLI app, something is holding onto that request and prevents your application from exiting, thinking that everything is done

In that case, you can chain the response with a `Mono<Void>` type, which is completed as `Mono.empty()` or an error:

```
public Mono<Void> some(MyObject myObject) {
    return webClient.post()
            .uri("/log/my-path")
            .body(BodyInserters.fromObject(myObject))
            .retrieve()
            .bodyToMono(Void.class)
            .then();
}
```

In other parts of your application, you can then chain again with other publishers:

```
Mono<Void> requestSent = some(myObject);
Mono<Other> other = requestSent.then(otherMono);
```

Comment: `then` does not work. The problem here is `bodyToMono` "blocks" execution. E.g. it "wait" for data retrivement and only after that mono can be finished. It there a way to skip blocking?

Comment: Doing that is supposed to read a bit of data and cancel+close the connection. The downside is, the connection is not returned to the connection pool. We've fixed several issues in that space (see https://jira.spring.io/browse/SPR-17482, https://jira.spring.io/browse/SPR-17054). So at that point, it's best for you to create a sample application with the latest Spring version that shows the issue and create a new issue on jira.spring.io